# How to send application usage and bug reports to Google docs?

Tags: java, api, bug-tracking

I talked yesterday to an Android app developer for a few minutes and he showed me a really cool feature: automated app crash reports reported directly inside a Google spreadsheets. Basically he made the app crash on purpose using some kind of easter eggs, then went on his Google docs accounts and, sure enough, the bug report was there.

From what I understood he's basically doing an HTTP POST to some Google server (I think to recall *spreadsheet.google.com* or something like that) everytime an app crashes and he gets all the info he needs.

What Google API, if any, was he using?  If no API is involved, how do you know how to format and encode your post?

Comment: Note that I'm interested in the same feature for a desktop app which *already* does this kind of reporting, but as of now it is contacting our very own server using our own custom formatting/encoding and if I could ditch that code and ease the load of our servers by directly filling Google docs, that would be lovely.

Comment: Oh and please, don't upvote answers without upvoting the question itself.  If a question is worth upvoting, so is the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Monitoring app activity: [Google Analytics for Android](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/android/)
2. Collecting Android logs: take a look at inner class CollectLogTask in [SendLogActivity](http://code.google.com/p/android-log-collector/source/browse/trunk/android-log-collector/src/com/xtralogic/android/logcollector/SendLogActivity.java)
3. Uploading to Google Docs: [Docs List API](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/) or [Spreadsheet API](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/)
4. Catching crashes: set [default uncaught exception handler](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29). Important: call System.exit() when you're done.

Comment: So *"Docs List API"* and *"Spreadsheet API"* can be used for a non-Android Java app?

Comment: Yes, this are basically REST apis

Answer (score 4):

This might be what you are looking for - ACRA (Application Crash Report for Android) http://code.google.com/p/acra/